# Viewport background-image small offset

Tags: ios, css, ipad, viewport

So I've had this issue for a while now. When I load my website ([ysbakker.eu](http://www.ysbakker.eu)) on my iPad, the background-image (which is way bigger than my screen resolution) has a offset on the right and on the bottom of 1 or 2 pixels. This may seem like a minor problem but it actually bugs me quite a lot. I don't know what causes this, perhaps a minor mistake in the viewport rendering engine.
I don't have this issue on my iPhone 4s, which uses the same software as my iPad Air 2.

Here's an image to display what I'm talking about:
[image]

It's probably not easy to see on the image since the offset is white as well... But it's really there, trust me. You can see it better by zooming in.

The background image is hosted on photobucket, I also tried storing it on my own server but that didn't change anything. Here's my css for reference:

```
body {
    background: url('http://i95.photobucket.com/albums/l159/ysbakk3r/478769_zpsbe3rwtgu.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Am I missing anything essential here? I think it shouldn't show the offset with my code like this. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I think I found the problem, just not how to solve it. When I zoom in on my iPad and scroll all the way right, there's no longer an offset. So I guess the page is zoomed out a tiny fraction. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
body {
    background: url('http://i95.photobucket.com/albums/l159/ysbakk3r/478769_zpsbe3rwtgu.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin:0
}
```

Comment: What satya means is: add a margin of 0, since the body by default has a small margin on all sides. adding margin of 0 removes this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it didn't remove the offset on the right side though, just on the bottom (which is a slight improvement!). So thanks, wouldn't have thought of it. And ty @Persijn for explaining. But it's still not entirely fixed :s I don't have this issue on my desktop, which is even more odd. I'll try using a different browser on my iPad, to see if this is a Safari-only problem.

Comment: Nope, the same problem occurs when opening my website on Chrome. It might have something to do with the resolution... I'll look further into it and keep you posted on the results.

Comment: I think I found the problem, just not how to solve it. When I zoom in on my iPad and scroll all the way right, there's no longer an offset. So I guess the page is zoomed out a tiny fraction. Any suggestions on how to solve this? (btw, the bottom offset is back as well, it just cached wrongly I suppose)